# Running multiple presets with babel-node (ES2015 and React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, npm-scripts

I have this npm script in my package.json

```json
"babel-node": "babel-node --presets es2015"
```

it runs everything that has to do with my server.

But when I try to render React elements to the DOM the browser gives me this error:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

So I tried adding the react preset but how do I tell the npm script to run the command with both presets in mind?

These two ways don't seem to work:

```
babel-node --presets react es2015
babel-node --presets react, es2015
```

Comment: Remove the space after the comma - `babel-node --presets react,es2015`

Answer (score 0):

You should load react preset first:

```
babel-node --presets=es2015,react
```